# What is the sence of "$f(x,y)$ is continuous at $x_0$ uniformly in $y$"?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, continuity, uniform-continuity

Consider a function $f(x,y): \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. I found the following phrase in a book: "$f(x,y)$ is continuous at $x_0$ uniformly in $y$". What does it mean?

I think that it means that $f(x,y) \to f(x_0,y)$ as $x \to x_0$ uniformly in $y$, that is for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x,y) - f(x_0, y)| < \varepsilon$ for all $(x,y)$ such that $|x - x_0| < \delta$ .

Could you please confirm if I am right and give some link to any book where it's written what does a phrase like "f(x,y) is continious at $x_0$ uniformly in $y$" mean?

I can't find such definition anywhere :(

Comment: Yes, that is the definition. In particular, since the $y$ is quantified with a 'for all' that is deeper inside the expression than the 'exists' that quantifies the $\delta$, then the $\delta$ doesn't depend on $y$.

Comment: I agree. You will not find this as a definition as is. [Continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Weierstrass_and_Jordan_definitions_(epsilon%E2%80%93delta)_of_continuous_functions) at $x_0$ is defined in every primer on Calculus. On the other hand, in general *uniformly in* $y$ means that any appearing constants do not depend on $y$, unless explicitly defined otherwise.

Comment: Compare with "$x\mapsto f(x,y)$ continuous at $x_0$, for each $y$": $\forall y\in A, \forall \epsilon>0,\exists \delta>0. \forall x\in B, |x-x_0|<\delta\implies |f(x,y)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$, where $A,B$ are whichever sets the $x$ and $y$ are allowed to take values from in the problem. The quantification of $y$ is further outside of that of $\delta$. Less formally you also see the $\forall y\in A$ not being written altogether.

Comment: @owl I realize the difference between $f(x,y)$ is continious at $x_0$ for all $y$, but I want to find the formal definition in any book. The phrase from the question looks like it's a classic object and I suddenly realized that I can't find the formal definition anywhere.

Comment: @Matija I agree that it's hard to find this definition in books, but it looks strange, because the phrase from the question looks like it describes a classic object.

Comment: @Kar No, that is an entirely different concept. That $y\mapsto f(x_0,y)$ is uniformly continuous means that $\forall \epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0, \forall y_1,y_2, |y_1-y_2|<\delta\implies |f(x_0,y_1)-f(x_0,y_2)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: @owl Oops! Good point, I entirely ignored continuity in the $x$-direction. But you (and OP) seem to be ignoring continuity in the $y$-direction. I can see how that's a valid interpretation of the given phrase, but couldn't it also mean that $f$ is continuous at $(x_0,y)$ in the multivariable sense? That is: $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0, \forall x,y,y_0\in\Bbb R, \|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)\|<\delta\implies |f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)|<\epsilon$

Comment: @Karl That phrase "uniformly on $y$" is not (usually) used to make any claim about continuity on the $y$. It is used, as someone was saying above, to say "[what is before] is independent on $y$". Even in "uniform continuity" one can read it as "the continuity statement, but independent of where is it". This is an unwritten rule for building terminology, like there is for concepts built with the qualification "local" or "locally". An author defining their own concept with the word "uniformly" in it could choose to not follow it, of course.

Comment: Right, but in the context of a function $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$, doesn't the word "continuous" itself refer (arguably) to continuity with respect to the standard topology of $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: @Karl Maybe, but since the location at which continuity is claimed is $x_0$, instead of something like $(x_0,y_0)$, makes it suggest that when they write $f(x,y)$ they are referring to $x\mapsto f(x,y)$.